# Truth-value injection in quasi-empirical theoriess

Tags: logic, empiricism, theory

While reading about quasi-empiricism I have encountered the following statement: "Thus the logical channels of theories are not downward transmission of truth but for upward re-transmission of falsity" [1].

What this statement mean? I understand that with a deductive system we can start with the statement and use truth-preserving rules to go to the bottom of the tree, for the axioms. But at the top we rather have nothing but a theorem to prove, not a true statement. Similarly, I wish to know a bit more what is this upward re-transmission of falsity.

[1] ["Problems in the Philosophy of Mathematics"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a1diPb5BB_wC&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201&dq=quasi-empirical&source=bl&ots=LG1v7YVxIM&sig=ACfU3U3A1wfMqpsm2UaopHDGyw1AVcj3LQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiwhrfawuXpAhU0aRUIHWf9C8A4FBDoATAAegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=quasi-empirical&f=false)

Comment: In an experiment we can falsify a theory (falsity travels from conclusion to premise) but we cannot prove it (an experimental outcome positive is not enough to assert that the premise of the theory is true).

Comment: It means that theories are built not to derive results from first principles *a priori* (top down) but to test whether conjectured first principles are consistent with experimental facts (bottom up). If a fact falsifies a principle so much the worse for the principle, the falsity of a factual claim transmits up the theory that predicted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the "upward re-transmission of falsity".

In empirical science we assume theories (hypotheses) **T** and deduce predictions: **P**. I.e. we have statements like **T → P**.

Then we test the prediction **P** with empirical data (e.g. through an experiment).

If the prediction is refuted by empirical evidence (it is falsified), we conclude that the theory **T** is wrong; see the valid inference called [Modus Tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens#Formal_notation).

If instead the prediction "fits" with data, we have verified it, but this is not enough to conclude that the theory is true; see the logical fallacy called [Affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent#Formal_description).

Thus, we can summarize it saying that truth works downward (from premise to conclusion) while falsity works upward (from conclusion to premise).

See also [Popper and falsificationism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-method/#PopFal).